# Is 4 really that significant?

Tags: set-theory

I have seen the ZFC theorem, (($2^{\aleph_n}$ $<$ $\aleph_\omega$ for all $n$ $\epsilon$ $\mathbb N$ ) $\rightarrow$ $2^{\aleph_\omega}$ $<$ $\aleph_{\omega_4}$). My question is whether this theorem is sharp. More precisely, is there some ZFC definable ordinal $\alpha$ less than $\omega_4$ which can replace $\omega_4$ in the statement of the theorem.

Comment: This is a significant open problem. We do not even know whether we can replace $4$ with $1$. We know $\omega_1$ cannot be lowered, though; this was shown by Shelah much earlier. The strongest result so far is due to Gitik, [here](http://www.tau.ac.il/~gitik/short%20extenders%20forcing%202-2015.pdf).

Comment: @AndrésCaicedo OP's inequality was first proved by Shelah, using his pcf theory, right?

Comment: @Stefan: Correct. And $4$ really just comes out of the proof. Because you need to go from $\omega_1$ to $\omega_2$, then to $\omega_3$, so you're left with just $<\omega_4$. It's not a magical number in any way, just a straightforward dashing counting argument.